# MeteorJS: How to configure which files are injected in <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs

I've come on to a project built in Meteor and React; I'm a Node/Angular kinda guy so this is all very new to me. The project is 95% done but has severe performance bottlenecks and I need to figure them out and fix them.

The biggest one I see is that when running the page, 110 javascript files are being loaded in, and they're 23mb in collective size. Pretty nuts.

I **don't** think these are needed by the react app at all, but Meteor is building them and injecting them in - I'm pretty sure they're actually used by Meteor. Some examples:

`allow-deny.js
audit-argument-checks.js
babel-compiler.js
babel-runtime.js
base64.js`

Things like that, which seem like Node server-side scripts.

So my question is: Where in the Meteor app structure are the files `<script>` tag injection declared, and how can I be sure that only the absolutely necessary files are being included?

Comment: Are you sure you run the app in production mode? In prod mode, there should only be a single, merged js file for the client. Build the app using `meteor build` and check the client side javascript size, or run your app using `meteor run --production`.

Comment: @aedm Nope, I run this and it still has all of those files being injected!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a production build then. Please note that Meteor only merges JS files for the client, not the server.